# Can the mass of an object be changed by adding opposing magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, mass

Apparently it does. Or is this voodoo physics. If not what is really happening in this case?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N2TS3VReTA Boyd Bushman Changed the mass of a black box object, rock. He took two black box rocks. One rock he added two magnets connected in oppositon S-N-N-S bolted together. And the other rock had no magnets. He then drop them both at same time from a 40 story building and the rock with magnetic fields in opposition canceled out the mass gravity to a small percent and fell more slowly then the rock with no magnetism. Real effect on not? Are there any field equations that tie gravity directly or indirectly to magnetism?

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously wrong: mass don't change. Now the *effects* of mass might be tilted by some other forces.
Moreover, the speed of free fall is not related to mass as well (at 1st order).

Comment: Force of gravity is a constant at 40 ft above earth. So both ojects should fall at the same rate. g = 9.8 meters/second2 if this has been changed it follows 1/M = G/F or M = F/G the mass has changed or the force acting on the mass has changed. Since we now the gravitational force is constant the mass must have been shielded in some way by the magnetic field in opposition. Thus the net gravitational mass has changed. Or antigravity force has appeared cancelling Fg.

Comment: Why do you absolutely want a "shielding of gravity" rather than considering that more than one force acts ? It I blow a balloon up, I'm not "shielding his mass". And, again, the speed of free fall is independant of mass and shape (if you neglect friction with air), so it tells nothing about the mass. You might pretend that attraction is modified (via G), but not mass.

Comment: The [frog's](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=diamagnetism+frog) mass isn't altered. And it isn't really gravitational shielding. It's just another force present. And because it's there, the effective force of gravity is reduced. To zero.

Comment: If I pick an object up with my hand, I oppose gravity with electromagnetic forces. This does not change the mass (or weight) of the object. Bolting two magnets onto a rock increases the mass of the rock by the mass of the magnets, plus a little stored energy. That's the only effect on the mass.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the mass of an object be changed by adding opposing magnetic fields?

Yes. When you push two opposing magnets together you add energy. So the mass increases. It's the same when you compress a spring.

> Apparently it does. Or is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N2TS3VReTA) voodoo physics?

That's interesting. I've never seen that before. I hesitate to say it's voodoo physics because a magnet [falls slowly through a copper pipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BeFoz3Ypo4).

> Boyd Bushman Changed the mass of a black box object, rock. He took two black box rocks. One rock he added two magnets connected in opposition S-N-N-S bolted together. And the other rock had no magnets. He then drop them both at same time from a 40 story building and the rock with magnetic fields in opposition cancelled out the mass gravity to a small percent and fell more slowly then the rock with no magnetism. Real effect on not?

I don't know. Sorry. I'd like to see somebody repeat this.

> Are there any field equations that tie gravity directly or indirectly to magnetism?

No, there aren't any. But note that an electron has an electromagnetic field. Not an electric field or a magnetic field, an *electromagnetic* field. So does a proton, or a copper ion. And when we arrange electrons and copper ions as the [current in the wire](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html), the opposite electromagnetic fields don't quite cancel, and we call the difference, the "residual trace field", a magnetic field. Then when we *stop* the electrons, the fields *still* don't quite cancel. There's still a residual trace field. But we don't call it a magnetic field any more.

Answer (score 1):

A simple magnet will fall slightly more slowly than a non-magnet because of extremely small eddy currents created in empty space (space has some level of permeability). However, if it is not shielded from the Earth's magnetic field, it should fall slightly faster because it is one large magnet (the earth) attracting the small magnet. Both effects are extremely small and I don't know which is greater.